# Another Zodiac Killer Puzzle

Tags: visual, steganography, real

[image]

This is a multi-part puzzle concerning the Zodiac Killer "Pines" card sent to the San Francisco Chronicle on March 22, 1971. I will ask it as a series of questions and hints, as I think it's too hard to solve the puzzle without them. The overall puzzle is "is the name of Edward Wayne Edwards in the card". Additional information: his birth name was Charles.

The first puzzle, is something easy, almost trivial, although even then, I have seen people stumped! Can you spot the "X"?

Second puzzle: can you see three monkeys? What noise do monkeys make?

Third puzzle: can you spot a wain?

Now a hint :

> Consider the pasted strings to be flags or pointers and the pole star.

Another hint:

> What is another name for the "Big Dipper"?

Finally, how does the card encode Edwards' name?

Good luck! I hope this is not too hard, but not quite trivial either. I didn't make this puzzle up, rather I got the solution from a woman who [says she was forced to make the card in 1971](https://ededwardsserialkiller.wordpress.com/pines-card-witness/), and it was explained to her.

Comment: For the first riddle, I have found "X"

Comment: @AntsPiano The "X" is not the Zodiac symbol bottom right.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is just a partial answer.
As I have been trying to find where “x” is I finally think I found it!

For puzzle no. 1

> Is this where the “x” is?[image: .]

Comment: Just because no one else is posting an answer or commenting doesn't mean that they're not working on a puzzle.

Comment: This has to be the most partial answer I've ever seen on PSE...! Maybe consider coming up with some theories about the other parts of the puzzle before posting what really is just a straightforward observation about something you can see in the picture?! ;-) There's never a rush to post just *something* on a puzzle on PSE - puzzles here can often take days or weeks before a true insight really strikes. My advice: before posting an answer, always aim to make it something great or interesting :)

Comment: Ok, thank you! So do I delete it for now?

Comment: It's not as easy to spot as that. Maybe I should have stated, "not the Zodiac X bottom right corner".

Comment: Is that the answer? Not sure

Comment: @AntsPiano This is the correct solution to puzzle 1. Well done! How long did it take for you to find it?

Comment: Hmmmmm, it took me a few seconds after turning the pic bigger.